# Why doesn't %A text formatting work with internal modules in F#?

Tags: f#, text-formatting

The following code does not format the string as expected (it just prints the fully qualified class name):

```
module internal MyModule.Types

type Action =
    | Add of int
    | Update of int * string
    | Delete of string

module internal MyModule.Print

open MyModule.Types

let printStuff (x:Action) =
    printfn "%A" x
```

However, if `MyModule.Types` is not specified as `internal`, the formatting works as expected.  Why doesn't the formatting work with `internal` modules?  Does it have to do with reflection?  Is there a workaround besides making the module public?

I should mention the modules are in separate .fs files.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, for example I get the output:

> λ .\SO180207.exe
>   Add 10
>   Add 5
>   Add 5
>   [||]

You can see that `Add 10` was printed. Also, as I accessed the internal module, both the value and the `printfn "%A"` statement was executed.

This is the structure of the project:

MyModule.fs file:

```
module internal MyModule.Types 

type Action =
    | Add of int
    | Update of int * string
    | Delete of string

let x = Add 5
printfn "%A" x
```

Program.fs file:

```
module MyModule.Program
open MyModule.Types

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let x = Add 10 
    printfn "%A" x // prints Add 10 
    printfn "%A" MyModule.Types.x // prints Add 5 twice
    printfn "%A" argv 
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

So maybe you can provide some more information of F# version, and the environment you are running on. It's possibe to `override x.ToString()` inside your type as well.

**Additional comment:**
To be honest there might be something with internal modules, as if I override `ToString()`, the internal module clearly doesn't like it, and terminates with `StackOverFlowException`. E.g. this works without the `internal` modifier:

```
module MyModule.Types 

type Action =
    | Add of int
    | Update of int * string
    | Delete of string
    override x.ToString() = sprintf "%A" (x,x)
let x = Add 5
printfn "%A" x
printfn "%A" (x.ToString()) |> ignore
```

> λ .\SO180207.exe
>   Add 10
>   Add 5
>   "(Add 5, Add 5)"
>   Add 5
>   [||]

Comment: I edited the question to more accurately reflect the actual code I am running.  The code is running F# 4.4.1.0 on .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: @Ralphie similar setup, but from what you are describing it seems `printfn` is using `"%O"` instead of `"%A"` when you set the internal modifier. Not particularly sure why that  is the case.